# Postgres secutiry - How to check current security precosions

Tags: postgresql, security

I want to check the current security precosions on a Postgres DataBase, but cant figure out how to list roles and what are they allowed to do.
Is there any quick way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The `\dp` backslash-command in psql is the obvious starting point.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

If you start it with `-E` it will show you the queries it runs for the backslash commands.

Other than that you can dig into `pg_roles` and similar in the system tables.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html